# Find out if any aggregations will have buckets without doing aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Aggregations in Elasticsearch are pretty expensive. Before actually computing aggregations, I would like to find out if an aggregation would have non-zero count. 
For eg. say based on my query, N documents are returned. Now I want to find out, if on these N documents, I aggregate over a certain field, will that aggregation have any buckets? If for all documents the field has null value or empty string, it should return false or 0. If even single document has field as non-empty string or non-null value, it should return true or a non-zero number. I don't really care about the count.

Is it possible to do in a way which is much faster than computing aggregation?

Comment: You can try to use the `exists` query in order to find out if documents have a value for a given field.

Comment: I don't get why does it matter? Running aggregation in such a case is not heavy! By the way the mentioned `exists` query will tell you that. Consider using `filter` rather than `query` in your search query because you do not need scoring in this case.

Comment: yes using exists filter inside the aggregations worked. Running aggregation is pretty heavy. In my case had around 25 aggregations over million documents. Query with aggregations takes almost twice the time.